# Can Jenkins used with python project?

Tags: jenkins

I'm developing a web application using python django. I want a CI service which can automatically pull the latest code from my github and run some test then deploy. I'm not familiar with CI, after searching for a while I found Jenkins seems to be a good solution. Can Jenkins be used for this?

Comment: Yes. But just commenting, because I can't tell you exactly **how**. I am working with a team where someone else did the work to setup Jenkins with Python & Django. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins can be used with any project.

Regarding pulling the latest code, add the [Jenkins GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) in order to be able to check  "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" under "Build Triggers".

That will launch your job on any new pushed commit on the GitHub repo.

From there, a Jenkins job can execute any command that you would do in command-line, provided the agent on which said job will be scheduled and executed has the necessary tools in its PATH (here python)

---

An alternative (which does not involved Jenkins) is to [setup a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) and a listener on your server which will detect a "push event" sent by said webhook.